# Dynamic Syntax Highlighting with AngularJS and Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-highlighting

I am building a site that illustrates common application vulnerabilities such as SQL Injection.  I am using **AngularJS** and **highlight.js** to create interactive examples.

*How can I make both AngularJS and highlight.js update my code snippets?*

## Example

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Good_man/Lv56y2yy/6/) demonstrates how entering `' OR 1=1 --` in the Email field could change the intended behavior of the query if the user's input is not validated or sanitized.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email='{{email}}' AND Password='{{password}}'
```

When a user enters an email address and password, Angular updates the query. However, syntax highlighting does not update.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email='user@domain.com' AND Password=''
```

I tried re-initializing hljs, but when I do angular stops updating the query.

```
hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
hljs.initHighlighting();
```

### Application

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", ['hljs']);
    app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
        $scope.email = "user@domain.com";
        $scope.password = "";
    })
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">Email
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">Password
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div hljs include="'compile-me'" compile="true" language="sql"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="compile-me">
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email = '{{email}}'
        AND Password = '{{password}}'
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the jsfiddle you have provided you're using [angular-highlightjs](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-highlightjs) which  in your case basically:

1. Fetches the template you have provided with `include` directive applies
2. Invokes [highlightjs](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) library API on the **template** which produces HTML markup with highlighted elements having correct style for particular language
3. The **highlighted HTML markup** is then passed over to angularjs `$compile`

Afterwards no highglighting takes place - in particular even when interpolated content changes.

One way to solve it is to use `source` directive from `angular-highlightjs` which is observed but I think it's simpler to build a custom directive.

The trick here is to manually interpolate and highlight content. I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv56y2yy/9/) with a simplistic `highlight` directive that presents the idea:

```
app.directive('highlight', function($interpolate, $window){
    return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: true,
    compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
      var interpolateFn = $interpolate(tElem.html(), true);
      tElem.html(''); // stop automatic intepolation

      return function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.$watch(interpolateFn, function (value) {
          elem.html(hljs.highlight('sql',value).value);
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  I changed .highlight() to .highlightAuto() for auto language detection, but I might need to specify the language later.  In those cases, I may create  a corresponding 'highlight-language' directive.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler way I just found is to use a filter:

```
app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(input, lang) {
    if (lang && input) return hljs.highlight(lang, input).value;
    return input;
  }
}).filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; })
```

Then you can say:

```
<pre><code ng-bind-html="someScopeVariable | highlight | unsafe"></code></pre>
```

The $sce needs to be injected into your app, and tells Angular to display the HTML raw - that you trust it.